# SVG (d3.js) and jQuery UI selectable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, d3.js, svg

I have a d3.js chart on which I'm trying to use jQueryUi Selectable plug-in while it shows the selection rectangle (no selecting effect as shown on plugin page) but once I release mouse nothing is selected. You can try on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mantrig/5b5698dr/

My code is somewhat like below :

```
<div class="selectable">
<svg height="90" width="200">
  <text x="10" y="20" style="fill:red;">Several lines:</text>
    <text x="10" y="45">First line.</text >
    <text x="10" y="70">Second line.</text >

 Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg></div>
```

--js script--

```
$(function() {
    $( ".selectable" ).selectable();
    }
  });
```

No class is getting add or remove on selection . These text elements are sample in my case these things will be dynamic from some json.

Comment: First off all it has to be $( "#selectable" ).selectable();

Comment: @Cyril thanks it was a typo..

Comment: Can you post more code is the selectable div
Like 
_<div class="selectable">
<svg> <text>Bye</text></svg>
<svg> <text>Hi</text></svg>
</div>_ .. or something else

Comment: @Cyril I have made one fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mantrig/5b5698dr/ take a look on it.

Comment: i tried it but it seems selectable plugin doesn't wrk with svg..may be some one else has some way :(

Comment: do you have to use jqueryUi selectable? because you can easily do it with d3 it self...